# Cannot edit email update schedule for Favorite Tags filter

Tags: bug, email-notification, tag-filters

When trying to edit my Favorite Tags email subscription from every 3 hours to daily I found that clicking the edit link does nothing.

Digging into the issue a little, it seems that when clicking the edit link the code attempts to click on an element with class `filter-edit` but no such element exists in the source code.

Favorite tags URL is https://stackexchange.com/filters/226082/favorite-tags

Screenshot showing the event handler:

[image: Event Handler]

Video attempting to show that clicking does nothing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8FPLb7P4lI

I've tried Chrome, IE, and Firefox.  All of them do nothing when clicking the link. I was able to edit the schedule by using the dev console to show the form manually then submit it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this - can you provide the actual URL of the page? Screen shots will help too.

Comment: @Oded, I've edited with additional information.